# Getting wrong output for my program in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int num(int n){
    for(int i= 1 ; i<=n ; i++){
       int sum=0;

       sum += i;
       cout<<sum;

     }
}
```

i guess this part is clear.

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    cout<<"enter the value of x ";
    cin>>x;

    int answer=num(x);
    cout<<"the total sum of the first n integer is "<<answer;

    return 0;
}
```

ive tried looking it up but no results found....
ive always had some trouble with the loops.

Comment: It is an obvious mistake: The function num should return the variable sum.

Comment: you can indent code by using 4 spaces

Comment: you can copy and past code from your editor to here, and then select and highlight all text that is to be in a code block and while still highlighted press ctrl + k. This will automatically indent each line with four spaces. It makes for faster editing on this website.

Comment: @prathmesh.kallurkar that is not the OPs only bug in the code.

Comment: @FrancisCugler I see it. It's the `int sum` within the loop. Defining `int sum` within the loop causes it to be destroyed and recreated every iteration of the loop. `int sum` will not persist through the entire loop and will therefore not contain any form of accumulated result. Scoping also prevents `int sum` from being returned from the function.

Comment: You know there is a formula for this, right? You don't need to actually run a loop.

Comment: i wrote return sum before , still no change

Comment: so? where do i declare sum?

Answer (score 3):

- You are throwing away what is calculated by previous iterations.
- You are not returning what is calculated.

To fix, get the declaration and initialization of `i` out of the loop and return the result.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int num(int n){
    int sum=0;
    for(int i= 1 ; i<=n ; i++){

        sum += i;
        cout<<sum;

    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: when i enter the number 3,  
     
this is displayed:"136the total sum of the n integer is 6"  
     
why is it that?

Comment: Because you printed the log via `cout<<sum;` in function `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the definition and initialization of the variable `sum` to outside of the for loop, preferably before it. Do not forget your return value from the function.

Answer (score 0):

The function `num()` should return the variable `sum` and variable `Sum` should be defined outside `for` loop.

Your code should be

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int num(int n){
       int sum=0; //sum should be declared outside for loop
         for(int i= 1 ; i<=n ; i++){
              sum += i;
             // cout<<sum;  //dont print sum here it will be printed in main()
         }
  return sum; //you missed this
}
```

---

```
int main()
{
       int x;
       cout<<"enter the value of x ";
       cin>>x;
       int answer=num(x);
       cout<<"the total sum of the first n integer is "<<answer;
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: i wrote that before , still no change

Comment: hey it finally works thx to you , but there is a number before my answer like:

Comment: when i enter the number 3,

Comment: this is displayed:"136the total sum of the n integer is 6"

Comment: @IanTwy in `int num(int n)` function dont use `cout<<sum;`. i will update the answer. Accept answer if it solved your problem!